# Do we have $\text{Proj} A[X] = \text{Spec} A$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

From the definition $\text{Proj} A[X] = \{ \text{ homogeneous ideals }\mathfrak p \in \text{Spec} A[X] \mid (X) \not\subset \mathfrak{p} \}$.

It seems to me that with this definition only the $A$-ideals remain, so that we at least have a homeomorphism on the points. But do we also have $\mathcal O_{\text{Proj} A[X]} = \mathcal O_{\text{Spec} A}$?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Your definition is not ideally suited for proving this, in the sense that your definition does not explain what $\mathrm{Proj}(A[X])$ is as a *scheme*. In (say) Vakil's ''Foundations of Algebraic Geometry'', Vakil explains how to cover $\mathrm{Proj}(S)$ by affine opens, where $S$ is a (positively) graded ring - see section 4.5, where this is all very clearly laid out. The point then becomes that for $S = A[X]$ with the usual grading, there is a single affine open which covers $\mathrm{Proj}(S)$, and the ring of global sections of this affine open is isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Thanks, I'll have a look at Vakil's notes again.